# How to recommend selection of one variable when the variables have p-values that are not statistically significant after applying holm adjustment

Tags: r, regression

My task is recommend to a marron farmer who wishes to farm in a new location, and have four locations with different amounts of rainfall. amount of rainfall is the important factor for the farmer to qualify a location for setting up  Marron farm. Multple comparisons were used to compare the locations and holm adjustment was used to control type 1 error rate. The analysis found that only two locations were significant different, the rest of the locations had p values > 0.05 which was set as alpha.of course the boxplot of the four locations was created and one location (Pemberton) even got an outlier way above all other locations, and its median line is above the other two medians though still overlapping with their boxes.

My problem is how do i pick one location based on the analysis? Below is the table of p-values generated

```
Table 2: Pairwise t-test results (p-values)

               Albany       Bunbury        Manjimup

Bunbury        0.41192      -              -       
Manjimup       0.14241      0.87340        -       
Pemberton      0.00031      0.13759        0.06522
```

Note: p-values have been adjusted to control the familywise type 1
error rate using the holm method.

Comment: Why would you not just go with the location that seems to have the highest rainfall? Is there any particular reason why you have to be protected against a "Type I error" where you get the highest location wrong due to measurement error?

Comment: A t-test is usually not appropriate for rainfall data anyway since it is usually not normal distributed.

Comment: These results are not adequate for answering the substantive question, because p-values tell the farmer almost nothing relevant about which location has optimal rainfall.  Indeed, what is the optimum anyway and why would that have anything to do with testing whether you can detect differences in rainfall at various locations?